# Core-Plot CPTScatterPlot data labels

Tags: ios, core-plot

When you create a scatter plot it auto-labels the points on the graph itself. I find this very annoying and want to shut it off as it isn't useful for what we are doing. Is there a way without removing all labels?

TO BE CLEAR, these show up without adding any annotations.. I want to remove this default behavior.

[image]

I want to remove the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 etc in the graph.

Here is the code I'm using to create the graph. As you can see it doesn't set any annotations, etc.

```
    -(void) constructScatterPlot
    {
    // Create graph from theme
    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];
    scatterPlotView.hostedGraph = graph;

    graph.paddingLeft   = 0.0;
    graph.paddingTop    = 0.0;
    graph.paddingRight  = 0.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0

    // Setup plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
    plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-2.5) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(28)];
    plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-5) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(desiredPeak+10)];

    NSArray *exclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-1) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-100)],
                                                         [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(25) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10000)], nil];

    // Axes
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"4");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    x.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    x.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 10;
    x.labelExclusionRanges = exclusionRanges;

    exclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-1) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-100)],
                                                [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(101) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10000)], nil];
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"10");
    y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 20;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    y.labelExclusionRanges = exclusionRanges;

    // Put an area gradient under the plot above
    CPTColor *areaColor       = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3 green:1.0 blue:0.3 alpha:0.8];
    CPTGradient *areaGradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor endingColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    areaGradient.angle = -90.0f;
    CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient];

    // Create a blue plot area
    CPTScatterPlot *boundLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    boundLinePlot.identifier = @"Blue Plot";

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    //lineStyle.miterLimit = 1.0f;
    lineStyle.lineWidth  = 3.0f;
    lineStyle.lineColor  = [CPTColor blueColor];
    lineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f], nil];
    boundLinePlot.dataSource     = self;
    boundLinePlot.cachePrecision = CPTPlotCachePrecisionDecimal;//Double;
    boundLinePlot.interpolation  = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;//Histogram;
    [graph addPlot:boundLinePlot];

    // Do a blue gradient
    CPTColor *areaColor1       = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8];
    CPTGradient *areaGradient1 = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor1 endingColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    areaGradient1.angle         = -90.0f;
    areaGradientFill            = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient1];
    boundLinePlot.areaFill      = areaGradientFill;
    boundLinePlot.areaBaseValue = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalValue];

    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAnimation.duration            = 1.0f;
    fadeInAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    fadeInAnimation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeInAnimation.toValue             = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    [boundLinePlot addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
}
```

So something is turned on by default..

Thanks for any and all help.

-David

Comment: symbolTextAnnotation = nil

Comment: where would I set this? I have not set anything, annotations, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Data labels" (labels above each point) do not appear by default. The automatic labels require both a `labelTextStyle` and `labelFormatter`. Both of these properties default to `nil` which hides the labels.

Comment: So where I set this to nil? on the graph itself? Or the plot?

Comment: Just tried: boundLinePlot.labelTextStyle = nil;
    boundLinePlot.labelFormatter = nil;
with no change.

Comment: What datasource methods have you implemented? `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` will obviously display data labels, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can also make it appear on the graph if you touch via:

```
    -(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot
plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    int plotNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [mainDataForPlot count]; i++)
    {
        if ([mainDataForPlot objectAtIndex:i] != [NSNull null]
            &&
            [(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",[[mainDataForPlot objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0],[[mainDataForPlot objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1]]
             ]) 
        {
            plotNumber = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (self.symbolTextAnnotation != nil) 
    {
        self.symbolTextAnnotation = nil;
    }

    // Setup a style for the annotation
    CPTMutableTextStyle *hitAnnotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";

    // Determine point of symbol in plot coordinates
    NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
    NSNumber *y = [[[mainDataForPlot objectAtIndex:plotNumber] objectAtIndex:3] objectAtIndex:index];
    NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil];

    // Add annotation
    // First make a string for the y value
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSString *yString = [formatter stringFromNumber:y];

    // Now add the annotation to the plot area
    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:yString style:hitAnnotationTextStyle] autorelease];
    self.symbolTextAnnotation = [[[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace  anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint] autorelease];
    self.symbolTextAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
    self.symbolTextAnnotation.displacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 20.0f);
    [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:symbolTextAnnotation];

}
```

Comment: Did you read the question? I am asking how to get these not to show up. I have not added any annotations.

Comment: David I understand your question. I was pointing out where they could be coming from not how to add them. You should post at least some of your code for anyone to be able to help you further. Best of luck.