# Core Plot - How to add Value on plotted points

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-plot

[image]I am using Core Plot first time for Plotting graph

Some how I finally managed to plot points but I want to show exact value of plotted point on the graph in annotation style.
I want to show exact points values same as shown in this Attached image(graph image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpyRj.png
Please help me

Thanks in advance
[image: graph image]

Comment: See this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreplot-discuss/iqKc5g5pTiQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to display data labels (that is what they are called in CorePlot), some good information are here [Core-Plot CPTScatterPlot data labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915558/core-plot-cptscatterplot-data-lables)

To show data labels, you'll need to return the corresponding values from

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Data labels do not appear by default. The automatic labels require both a labelTextStyle and labelFormatter to be set. Both of these properties default to nil which hides the labels.

Comment: thanks for your response and knowing me that these are called Data Labels, but I have gone through link but could not find any information that how to add those Data Labels.

Comment: The *Plot Gallery* example app has several plots that demonstrate this method. The "Donut Chart" demo even includes a border, rounded corners, and a fill behind the labels. Core Plot doesn't support the callout shape in your example, but you could draw it with an image fill with the correct shape.

Comment: @EricSkroch Thanks for response,I have one issue is my dataLablels are plotted for only visible points and not for points which are scrollable

Comment: If you're using custom data labels (via the datasource method above), the plot should ask for labels for each data index. The labels will scroll with the plot.

Comment: @EricSkroch As you said the method is called for all points. But the custom labels which are plot using this methods are visible for points which are in visible context & not for points which are out of current context & needs to scroll graph to see.  Any solution for this?

Comment: This should work as you describe. What version of Core Plot are you using? If you're on a recent version (1.4 or later), please report a bug on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues?state=open).

Comment: @EricSkroch Now got your point something and problem as well, I will try that thanks once again.

Comment: @EricSkroch I have saw the "Donut Chart" demo but how could I draw callout shape with an image fill.Can you give any code example or in which method can i do this Implementation.